# What is the directory /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External used for?

Tags: xcode, development, sound-volume

I'm using Mono to compile .NET code. A coworker tried to compile the same code and got this error:

> "/Users/us/Development/sample/src/vasone.sln" (default target) (1) ->
> "/Users/us/Development/sample/src/Sample.Avalonia/Sample.Avalonia.csproj" (default target## Heading ##) (27) ->
> /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.404/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file '/Users/us/Development/sample/src/Sample.Avalonia/obj/project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [/Users/us/Development/sample/src/Sample.Avalonia/Sample.Avalonia.csproj]

We found out that my coworker didn't have this folder:

**/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External**

The thing is that the Mono installer doesn't create it.

What is it used for, and why do I have it and my coworked doesn't?

Comment: Please specify the versions of OS, Mono and method of installation of Mono.

Comment: What has the directory you name to do with the error which gives a complete path name?

Comment: MacOSX Monterey, Mono 6.12.0.122, installed via installer via www.mono-project.com